# Can't figure out Object required error

Tags: vba, excel

The purpose of the code is to send an email to a list of addresses. To determine the start point, a user form will appear asking for the stating Column and Row (with plans that as I improve, I'll add other options in).

I had the code working, however, I made some tweaks and not keep getting an Object required error which I've tried figuring out for hours without luck. Please can you take a look at my code and suggest where I might be going wrong?

NB. I also tried declaring all variables but it didn't fix the issue.

The error is on the *Loop Until username.Value = ""*

```
Sub cmdGo_Click()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

i = cmbRow

If i = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

username = cmbColumn

If username = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Select Case username

    Case "A", "a"
        username = Cells(i, "a").Value
    Case "B", "b"
        username = Cells(i, "b").Value
    Case "C", "c"
        username = Cells(i, "c").Value
    Case "D", "d"
        username = Cells(i, "d").Value
    Case "E", "e"
        username = Cells(i, "e").Value

End Select

Do

Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail

        .To = username
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Importance = 1
        .Subject = "Hello"
        .HTMLBody = "Message"

'display shows each email before sending
          .Display
'send sends email automatically
'         .Send

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

i = i + 1

Loop Until username.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: the line `username.Value = ""` indicates that the `username` variable *should be* set as a `Range`. It appears in your code that `username` is a variant type, since you do not ever declare `username` as a specific variable type. The quick fix is to make the line `username = ""`. The correct fix is to use [Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) at the top of your module and declare all your variable types explicitly. In the case of `username`: `Dim username as String`

Comment: What is the loop meant to do? i is never used?

Comment: Granted, but these are outside the loop.

Comment: Surely the Do is in the wrong place? If it were below the i = cmbRow line then it would Vicky through the users correctly? As it is, it would surely be on an endless loop of the same username?

Comment: Hence the "I'm a rookie to VBA and am struggling with a code I have written" :)

Comment: I tried to use `username = ""'`, however it got me stuck in an infinite loop. 

The loop is there because the code is intended to go through a list of email addresses and send an email to each one, so e.g. the starting point is cell A1, it will email the address held in A1, then go on to A2 etc. until a blank is found, at which point the loop will end.

Comment: @StevenWalker - I am drafting an answer now that should clean your code and having it working correctly :)

Comment: Thanks @HenryW. I thought it might have been but I was struggling to puzzle it out. That part is now resolved although I'm still getting the object error.

Comment: Thanks @ScottHoltzman - I'm looking forward to it!! :)

Comment: You may find that by saying where username= " " you inadvertently run a blank username through the loop which causes the error. Instead, try username.offset(1,0)=" "   This should cause it to stop when the cell below the current one is blank

Comment: @StevenWalker: one big tip I can give you is to indent your code properly and consistently (a good habit); this will allow you to see more easily why the loop never ends.  And of course the tip from Scott Holtzman about Option Explicit; it prevents typing mistakes and also gives you access to Intellisense which shows you what members are allowed or not (i.e. it tells you "username." leads to nothing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few syntax and understanding mistakes in the code. I have listed them below and refactored your code a bit to help to get it work as you desire.

1. It's always best to use [Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) at the top of each module and **explicitly** declare variables with the desired type
2. Place the setting of the username inside the loop so it resets each time with a new email based on the `i = i+1` counter.

Rest of comments are in code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub cmdGo_Click()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If cmbRow = "" or cmbColumn = "" Then 
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim i As Long
i = cmbRow

Dim UserNameCol As String 'created a new variable just to get column letter so can be used later in the loop and removed the `Select Case` block.
UserNameCol = cmbColumn

'set outlook outside loop since you only need to call it once, doing it in loop creates unneccesary processing
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Do Until Len(Cells(i, UserNameCol).Value) = 0 'will stop when blank cell appears

    Dim UserName As String
    UserName = Cells(i, UserNameCol).Value 'always will user whatever column choosen

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0) 'this goes here because a new email is needed each time
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail

        .To = UserName
        '.CC = "" 'you can remove this lines because you are not putting anything in the field
        '.BCC = "" 'you can remove this lines because you are not putting anything in the field
        .Importance = 1
        .Subject = "Hello"
        .HTMLBody = "Message"

        'display shows each email before sending
        .Display
        'send sends email automatically
        '.Send

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    i = i + 1

Loop 

'destroy outlook when finished processing all mails
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I now get a Run-time error 13 = type mismatch?
Not sure if there's something else in my set up I have wrong?

Edit: I removed the `i = "" or` and left the `If UserNameCol = " "...` which seemed to resovle it.

Comment: Nice clean-up, but the checking for UserName="" can best be done before the mail creation; i.e. make it a do while... loop, or wrap the whole innards of the loop in a (secondary) big If Then statement checking for <>"".

Comment: @CarlColijn - Edited previous, I just had to make a slight tweak and it works :)

Comment: @StevenWalker - yes, I see my error in the way I originally set it up. A `Long` variable cannot `=""`. I adjusted the test to continue the code in my edit. Please let me know if there is anything else that is not working.

Comment: All perfect @ScottHoltzman :) It gives me one extra email with a blank 'To'. I'm guessing this is because the instruction to create an email is before the loop until statement?

Comment: @StevenWalker - I fixed that. Carl Colijn had the find on that one. Try the edited code now.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks everyone. Looking forward to trying to build on it :)